# Strange facebook crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

Here is the bug report

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x103c2faa4 swift_getObjectType + 60
1                          0x102e3dc58 @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, open : URL, sourceApplication : String?, annotation : Any) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
2                          0x102f5e730 -[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy object:selector:application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] + 4303562544
3                          0x102f5d8e4 __47-[FIRAuthAppDelegateProxy initWithApplication:]_block_invoke.199 + 4303558884
4                          0x102ee6aa0 -[FIRAAppDelegateProxy application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] + 4303071904
5  UIKit                          0x18e064acc __58-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:]_block_invoke + 880
```

It crashes after user grant access from facebook app and turns back to my app.

Any idea what may the problem be like?

Comment: check this code `AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, open : URL, sourceApplication : String?, annotation : Any)`  in your app

Comment: I think there would be some message also with the crash logs. Is it whole crash log you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this code.in app delegate

```
   //For Facebook
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in AppDelegate

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {  ...   }

 @available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {   ...   }
```